# How to pull out latitude/longitude coordinates from MKMapItem

Tags: core-data, mapkit, cllocation, mkmapitem

I'm creating an app that uses CoreData to store points of interest. `MKMapItem` coordinates are accessible within `mapItem.placemark.location`. I'd like to pull out the individual latitude and longitude coordinates and store them in a `managedObjectContext` as `double`s. How would I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For every easy question, there's an easy answer:

```
mapItem.placemark.location.coordinate.latitude
mapItem.placemark.location.coordinate.longitude
```